# Is the port number the same when connecting to git via the git+ssh protocol?

Tags: ssh, git, port-forwarding, port, protocol

I was wondering when connecting to a git repository, does the git+ssh protocol use the same port number as just using the git protocol. For example:

git://example.com/git/helloworld

git+ssh://root@example.com/git/helloworld

I am trying to push to a remote repository that has port forwarding setup on only the git protocol port number (9418) using EGit. When I try and use the git+ssh, EGit tells me

```
git+ssh://.... connection is closed by foreign host
```

Thanks,

Tomek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git+ssh is git over the ssh client. As such it uses the SSH port (22) and not the git port.